# В каких контекстах употребляются слова "человеки", "человекам", и т. д.?

Tags: множественное-число

Обычно, слово "человек" в множественном числе будет "люди", "людей", "людям" и т.д. Но иногда встречается со словами "человеки", "человекам" и т.д. В каких контекстах они употребляются?

Comment: Consider Matthew 4:19 "Follow Me, and I will make you _fishers of men_" in Russian it's "идите за Мною, и Я сделаю вас _ловцами человеков_"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Судя по [странице](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA#.D0.A1.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0) в викисловаре, "человеки" - это устаревший вид множественного числа.
Также такая форма употребляется для придания ироничного, нарочито странного оттенка фразе ("все мы люди, все мы человеки").

Comment: Есть ли у вас какие-то примеры использования?

Comment: @PeterOlson [все мы люди-человеки](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/1550/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5); [Мы греки, цесны человеки](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/29380/%D0%9C%D1%8B); [Гараж(фильм): Люди! Люди! Человеки!!!](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC)); [Библия. Синодальный перевод](http://algart.net/bible/synodal/bible.html).

Answer (score 9):

Мне кажется, в основном, "человеки" употребляется когда надо подчеркнуть что речь идет именно о людях (не об инопланетянах (рептилоиды, зеленые человечки и т.д.), не о фентезийных расах (эльфы, гномы и иже с ними) и не о ком-нибудь еще).

Часто используется когда говорящий не позиционирует себя как человека (например говорит от имени кота)

Comment: Ага, "Слава роботам! Убить всех человеков!" (с) Бендер, "Футурама" :-D

Answer (score 2):

Лично я использую слово "человеки", когда хочу подчекнуть их индивидуальность. Т.е. не просто толпа (люди), а именно человеки (где важен каждый человек). Такое использование слова не очень распространено и не вполне грамматически корректно, но иногда бывает полезным.

Кстати, в примерах из других ответов: "мы все люди, все человеки" и "убить всех человеков", думаю, используются именно этот смысловой оттенок.